# How to write URLs for views.py methods

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to display all of the details in an HTML page, but my problem is with my `urls.py`. It shows only the first URL and not the following URLs.

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Name, Description, WorkType, Hours, Price, PricePeriod,
    DateCreated, DateModified


def name(request):
    name = Name.name_text
    context = {'name': name}
    return render(request, 'poc_html/index.html', context)

def description(request):
    description = Description.description_text
    context = {'description': description}
    return render(request, 'poc_html/index.html', context)

    def worktype(request):
    worktype = WorkType.worktype_text
    context = {'worktype': worktype}
    return render(request, 'poc_html/index.html', context)

def hours(request):
    hours = Hours.hours_text
    context = {'hours': hours}
    return render(request, 'poc_html/index.html', context)

def price(request):
    price = Price.price_text
    context = {'price': price}
    return render(request, 'poc_html/index.html', context)

def priceperiod(request):
    priceperiod = PricePeriod.priceperiod_text
    context = {'priceperiod': priceperiod}
    return render(request, 'poc_html/index.html', context)

def datecreated(request):
    datecreated = DateCreated.datecreated.text
    context = {'datecreated': datecreated}
    return render(request, 'poc_html/index.html', context)

def datemodified(request):
    datemodified = DateModfied.datemodified_text
    context = {'datecreated': datemodified}
    return render(request, 'poc_html/index.html', context)
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.name, name='name'),
    url(r'^$', views.description, name='description'),
    url(r'^$', views.worktype, name='worktype'),
    url(r'^$', views.price, name='price'),
    url(r'^$', views.priceperiod, name='priceperiod'),
    url(r'^$', views.hours, name='hours'),
    url(r'^$', views.datecreated, name='datecreated'),
    url(r'^$', views.datemodified, name='datemodified'),
]
```

Comment: All of your `urlpatterns` capture the same thing, *only an empty URL*. Please read a tutorial (see e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/), you clearly have absolutely no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Actually, all those patterns capture the empty URL only. But I think the problem is deeper than that. I doubt very much OP wants separate pages for the name, description, worktype, etc; note how they all render the same template. It actually looks like he wants a single URL and a single view, which just renders a single model instance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the urls to navigate to a proper view definition.
You can do the following:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^name/$', views.name, name='name'),
url(r'^description/$', views.description, name='description'),
url(r'^worktype/$', views.worktype, name='worktype'),
url(r'^price/$', views.price, name='price'),
url(r'^priceperiod/$', views.priceperiod, name='priceperiod'),    
url(r'^hours/$', views.hours, name='hours'),
url(r'^datecreated/$', views.datecreated, name='datecreated'),
url(r'^datemodified/$', views.datemodified, name='datemodified'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, change your url patterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

Add unique route for each view

Or combine all data in ONE route + view!